# Pyspark crashing on Dataproc cluster for small dataset

Tags: apache-spark, group-by, google-cloud-dataproc, pyspark

I am running a jupyter notebook created on a gcp dataproc cluster consisting of 3 worker nodes and 1 master node of type "N1-standard2" (2 cores, 7.5GB RAM), for my data science project. The dataset consists of ~0.4 mn rows. I have called a `groupBy` function with the `groupBy` column consisting of only 10 unique values, so that the output dataframe should consist of just 10 rows!

It's susprising that it crashes everytime I call `grouped_df.show()` or `grouped_df.toPandas()`,  where grouped_df is obtained after calling `groupBy()` and sum() function.

This should be a cakewalk for spark which was originally built for processing large datasets. I am attaching the spark config that I am using which I have defined in a function.

```
builder = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Spark NLP Licensed") \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "40G") \
    .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer") \
    .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "2000M") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.johnsnowlabs.nlp:spark-nlp_2.11:2.5.1") \
    .config("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem") \
    .config("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
return builder.getOrCreate()
```

`
This is the error I am getting. Please help.
[image]

Comment: `.master(local[*])` means you're running your app locally, in your notebook, and not on the cluster.

Comment: @mazaneicha what should it be then?

Comment: URL for your master, see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls

Comment: Thanks. Will try

Answer (score 1):

Setting master's URL in setMaster() helped. Now I can load data as large as 20GB and perform groupBy() operations as well on the cluster.
Thanks @mazaneicha.